# Combo box with single image in the header

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a combo box that is bound to a list of strings. The combo box has a check box next to each value so the user can choose values.

I do not want the user to be able to "select" an item. when the combo box drop down is not open I always want a single image to show. So this would look a lot like a button but with a drop down list of check boxes.

I have already done the check boxes and text box so I dont need help with that, but I cant seem to find out how to achieve this.

C#
WPF
Visual Studio 2012

Comment: Read this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/563862/Multi-Select-ComboBox-in-WPF

Comment: If you don't want the normal behaviour of a `ComboBox`, then quite simply, don't use a `ComnboBox`. Use the [`Popup` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.